# Anyone running headless android application tests reliably under jenkins?

Tags: java, android, jenkins, emulation, headless

I have a pretty average Intel Core i5 750 and an nVidia GTX 660 graphics card running under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS amd64.

Problem: the android emulator plugin often tells me that the emulator (kvm/x86) does not come up ("device offline"). It is pretty much random. In addition to that, I was never able to take screenshots inside the UiAutomatorTestCase. (android api level 19, os 4.4.2)

I already found out the trick with the -no-audio option that prevents a problem with headless kvm. In addition to that I found out that one should omit the abi configuration entry in the android emulator plugin for jenkins -- otherwise you get a "userdata.img not found" error (or similar).

Question: is there *anyone* who runs android emulator tests reliably and headless under jenkins? If so, how???

Comment: Short answer: probably. But in reality this is probably too broad to answer.

Comment: It is broad because I need example setups against which I may compare my own one.